# material design for Nativescript with angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-material, nativescript

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 3.1.0           │ 3.1.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 3.1.0          │ Not installed │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

I want to use https://material.angular.io/ to my project . How to cofigure . i getting error in @angular/animation package.

Comment: do you have animation package in package.json file?
also what is the error?

Comment: Keep in mind that nativescript may support some of the angular.material package, but it likely WON'T support the components **at all**. Nativescript works with wrappers that are converted into native elements: the html `<input>`, in fact, in nativescript is a `<TextField>`, hence the two elements hate NOTHING in common, which forces you to adopt different approaches. However, Nativescript already includes some pre-done wrappers and allows you to use native wrappers, so you technically can do that manually, and you should start by checking this first: http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme

Answer (score 0):

The Android implementation of Material Design is already available in NativeScript and you can use it directly or via some plugins that also offer the iOS counterpart.

Regarding you specific question, the library you are talking about (Angular Material 2) is a web-based library and cannot be used in NativeScript as it doesn't use a browser to render the view (it actually uses the native elements).

About animation, please use the NativeScript implementation, you can find more info here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation